# Is there a limit of $\cos (n!)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I encountered a problem today to prove that $\cos (n!)$ does not have a limit. I have no idea how to do it formally. Could someone help? The simpler the proof (by that I mean less complex theorems are used) the better.

Comment: This seems like the wrong place to ask. The faq http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot has a list of suggested sites for good places where you can ask non-research level questions.

Comment: This site isn't meant for homework problems, or problems at the level of homework. So, if this is something you were assigned or found in an undergraduate text, we probably don't want it here. On the other hand, I have to admit, I don't see how to do this one.

Comment: I'd like to suggest you move your question to the math.stackexchange website. Or perhaps Ask Dr. Math. 

Comment: It has a limit if the argument of the function is expressed in degrees.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a homework/assignment, but you are right about low level of this problem. I'll post it in more appropiate place.

Comment: The question is now here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/is-there-a-limit-of-cos-n

Comment: It may not be research level, but then again, it's a little bit of a tough call as to what qualifies as a research question. I agree with David that this problem might not be trivial, but closely related problems (such as showing that $\cos(n)$ has no limit) are well-trodden ground.

Comment: The question boils down to whether the sequence $cn!$ tends to a limit mod 1, where $c=1/(2\pi)$. There are transcendental numbers $c$ for which the sequence DOES tend to a limit mod 1, so we have to use something about $\pi$. I'm sorry to see the question closed

Comment: The question was closed (or at least I voted to close) because it is not a good question, even though a good answer might derive from a related question.  It's unmotivated and, protestations to the contrary, it does look like homework in the sense the OP is asking for a proof of something which the OP knows to be true.  If the question were to be rewritten in a more appropriate fashion, then I would be happy to vote to reopen.


Comment: I've started a meta conversation over at http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/741/does-lim-cosn-exist/

Comment: IMO it would have made sense for people to participate in the meta thread rather than to have an close/open tug-of-war with no discussion.  Oh well. 

Comment: Rather than perpetuate the close/open tug-of-war, I would like to know if the questioner is still interested in knowing more about this question beyond what David has already said at math.SX.  I would also like to encourage those who reopened it to participate in the discussion at meta that David links to above so that we can all understand your reasoning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was always borderline, OP did not answer to question for years, and the question exists highly voted with an answer on [math.se]